# rotating object in canvas android

Tags: android

I have this code which prints 4 rectangles, but I want one of them to be rotated and this code works with those comments lines, but if I take them out it does not print that *rectangle4*

```
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        red_fill = new Paint();
        red_fill.setColor(Color.RED);
        red_fill.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        rectangle.set((getWidth() / 2 + 150), getHeight() / 2 - 20, (getWidth() / 2) + 170, (getHeight() / 2));
        rectangle2.set((getWidth() /2 - 10), getHeight() / 2 - 200, (getWidth()/2) + 10, (getHeight()/2) - 180);
        rectangle3.set((getWidth() / 2 - 170), getHeight() / 2 - 20, (getWidth() / 2) - 150, (getHeight() / 2));
        rectangle4.set((getWidth() / 2 - 130), getHeight() / 2 - 120, (getWidth() / 2) - 110, (getHeight() / 2) - 100);

        canvas.drawRect(rectangle, red_fill);
        canvas.drawRect(rectangle2, red_fill);
        canvas.drawRect(rectangle3, red_fill);
        //canvas.save();
        //canvas.rotate(45);
        canvas.drawRect(rectangle4, red_fill);
        //canvas.restore();

        invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: use `canvas.rotate(5);` for example, most likely your rect went off your screen after rotation

Comment: To add to that, use `canvas.rotate(degrees, centerX, centerY)`, where centerX/centerY are the center points of the Rect, i.e. `canvas.rotate(45, rectangle4.centerX(), rectangle4.centerY());`